# How to handle line data in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have laoded my **lines data** in MS-SQL in one table. I have **points data** in DBMS as well in separate table . When I open both table the map window would show lines and points as I want but now when I join more points the data is updated to **points table**. And since point table is table to store points only and line table is to store line data only. How is it possible to solve this issue so that when I connect points Line table is updated?

> I am using
>
> 1. Microsoft SQL 2008
> 2. Connect the dots Tool to connects points ( actually I need line
>      data in line table)
> 3. Mapinfo 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run the connect the dots tool again.  The editable layer, I presume, is the dots layer, so when you are creating the points, it automatically appends the data.

It seems to me, that you should load ALL of your point data, and then run the points to lines tool.

Have you not thought about adding the lines manually direct to the line table?

Comment: Can I store points and line in same table ?

Comment: This is not a true answer, just a suggestion. You could create a view in SQL Server that creates a line using the two points in your points table. In this way the lines will be created when you open the view. All you need to do is create new points. If you have more than two points in each line it will get a bit more tricky, but using a Userdefined Function could do the trick

Comment: PS: SQL Server does support multiple spatial coulmns in a single table, but I'm not sure how MapInfo Pro would. Of course the MapInfo-MapCatalog would specify which column to use for the spatial data, but ...

Comment: @Hairy when I add line manually the co-ordinate are not added automatically

Comment: So you need a point table, with point data in it?  Not just spatial data for the line?  If so, just create all of your points, then run the tool.  As peter said, you can store lines and points in the same table, with more than one spatial column.  However, MapInfo will only see one through the mapcatalog